# Oracle trimspool only trailing blanks (not leading blanks)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am wondering if there's any tricks to get `trimspool` to only trim trailing whitespace on the right.

I have code that uses dbms_output.put_line to print to the console, and the output often has indentation to make it easier to scan with the eyes. I set the line width rather large to make some of the output easier to read, so I also set trimspool to get rid of extra white space. The only problem is that now the leading which space is removed as well as the trailing whitespace. Is there a way to fix this? I could add a leading (before the leading whitespace) "`.`" character to some of the output statements, but I'm not allowed to modify the code in most of the packages.

---

Here's what it outputs with no trimmimg:

```
 level 1                          (EOL)
     level 2                      (EOL)
       Some data                  (EOL)
```

Here's what it currently outputs with `trimspool` on:

```
level 1(EOL)
level 2(EOL)
Some data(EOL)
```

HEre's what I want:

```
 level 1(EOL)
     level 2(EOL)
       Some data(EOL)
```

Comment: +1, handling whitespace output in SQL*Plus is a source of continuing confusion for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you're after

```
set serveroutput on size 100000 format wrapped
```

if I do understand your question.

If I do this:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000

begin
  dbms_output.put_line('no indent');
  dbms_output.put_line('   indent');
end;
/
```

SQL*Plus outputs:

```
no indent
indent
```

If, however, I do

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000 format truncated

begin
  dbms_output.put_line('no indent');
  dbms_output.put_line('   indent');
end;
/
```

SQL*Plus outputs:

```
no indent
   indent
```

You have to `set trimspool on` in order to eliminate the spaces up to `eol`.

Comment: `set serveroutput on size 100000 format wrapped` restores the whitespace on the left, but now there's lots of whitespace on the right (filesize is now almost doubled). `set serveroutput on size 1000000 format truncated` truncates some of the output lines (not good).

Comment: yup, the magic combination seems to be `set serveroutput on size 100000 format wrapped` with `set trimspool on`. Thanks!