# how to split a string into characters using plsql block

Tags: plsql

```
 declare
 str varchar2(20):='&your_string';
 begin
 for i in 1..length(str)
 loop
 dbms_output.put_line(substr(str,i,1));
 end loop;
 end;
 /
```

I am trying to split a string into characters and I want to print those characters one in each line. I am trying to print them with the above code but it is not  printing space characters. If anyone have idea please help me?

Comment: What do you want space character to look like? Replace it with your own representation `dbms_output.put_line(replace(substr(str,i,1), ' ', '<space>'));`

Comment: it is working when i replaced any other character in place of space but, but my actual requirement is i don't want to print any other character in place of space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you're running the PL/SQL block in `sqlplus`, right ? `dbms_output` + `sqlplus` combination itself is a tricky and when you mix that with `whitespace` you're in trouble. My advice in to avoid `whitespace` sensitive `dbms_output` and preferably `dbms_output` completely.

It is possible to get the output you want with some [sqlplus settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760949/272735). Please see the example below:

Empty line magically disappears:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  dbms_output.put_line('1');
  dbms_output.put_line(' ');
  dbms_output.put_line('2');
end;
/

1
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Empty line appears:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size 100000 format wrapped
SQL> set trimspool on
SQL> begin
  dbms_output.put_line('1');
  dbms_output.put_line(' ');
  dbms_output.put_line('2');
end;
/
1

2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

this code is ok might be you haven't put serveroutput on try this

declare

str varchar2(20):='i n dia';

begin

for i in 1..length(str)

loop

dbms_output.put_line(substr(str,i,1));

end loop;

end;

even with spaces

the code is same

Comment: The code is ok no problem if i am able to ub=nderstand the guy is not getting the o/p with spaces . please correct if there is anything else required

Comment: i set serveroutput on but it still not

Comment: you want o/p like this         i
 
n
 
d
i
a this code is ok for that